# Quickbooks Desktop api get sales tax rates with corresponding sales tax code

Tags: quickbooks

I am working on an app in which I need to fetch Sales Tax Rate with its corresponding sales tax code. For example, in my quickbooks instance I have Sales Tax Code as 'G' with Sales Tax Rate being '5%' . Similiarly I have 'HST' as Sales Tax Rate being '13%' and so on. These can be added or modified in future. So I need to export them from Quickbooks to save them to my PHP MYSQL database table.
But I cannot find a relationship between them in the Quickbooks Desktop API (OSR) which I am refering to. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the QuickBooks desktop SDK does not expose the relationship between `Sales Tax Codes` and `Sales Tax Items` (tax rates).

Comment: See my answer above. No. The desktop SDK (i.e. the API) does not expose that relationship.